# javascript getting value from one to multiple data-testid tags

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Using a tampermonkey script to get the text value from 1 to many possible data-testid tags. The page can have one or up to x of them that look like this. Need to extract Mercedes and all of the Auto's from any data-testid="autombile" on the page.

```
<span class="something" data-testid="automobile">
Auto:
<b>Mercedes</b>
</span>
```

Tried using different getElementById parameters.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid]').forEach( el => { console.log(el.textContent) });